# What potions/bombs does a Leech have access to starting the game?

Tags: blades-in-the-dark

As a Leech, I have a Bandolier that allows me to use three potions or bombs during a score.

Am I allowed to use only items I have created during downtime? Or can I use any item without having to spend downtime to craft?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main book has more detail on items than the character sheet does.

> Bandolier: A strap worn across the body, fitted with specially-padded
> pouches to hold three alchemical agents or spark-craft bombs. When you
> employ an alchemical or bomb from a bandolier, choose one from the
> list at right (or one of your custom-made formulas). See page 226 for
> more on alchemicals and bombs. During downtime, you automatically
> refill your bandoliers, so long as you have reasonable access to a
> supplier or workshop. [1 load]

You don't have to explicitly create the standard potions/bombs, and (under normal circumstances) it refills between scores.

Comment: The problem is that page 226 has an example downtime activity to create a poison from the aforementioned list at right, which seems at odds.

Comment: That (a) tells you their effects and (b) lets a character using a different playbook without access to the Bandolier create them.